# Better "In-Place" Amplification of QMA

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, qma

$\def\braket#1#2{\langle#1|#2\rangle}\def\bra#1{\langle#1|}\def\ket#1{|#1\rangle}$ 
In [MW05](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0506068) the authors demonstrate so-called "in-place" amplitude amplification for QMA, exhibiting a method for Arthur to amplify his success probability without requiring any increase in the size of Merlin's witness state. Call the original machine $M$ and the amplified machine $M'$.

Suppose that $x$ is the input, the original machine is  $M(x,w)$ and the amplified machine  is $M'(x,w)$. The approach of MW05 does not guarantee that a witness state that was in the accepting set for $M(x,\cdot)$ (i.e. that made $M$ accept input $x$ with probability exceeding, say, $\frac{2}{3}$)  is still in the accepting set for $M'(x, \cdot)$ (i.e. those states that make $M'(x, \cdot)$ accept with amplified probability). I explain why I think that it's actually not possible to make their method do this below the line.

**Q: Is there a way to perform amplification of QMA machines without increasing the length of Merlin's witness and while also guaranteeing that all initially valid witnesses for a given input stay valid witnesses for this input?**

---

Without explaining too much context and using their notation, the issue that seems to arise is that MW05 first proves that their approach works for states that are eigenvectors of $Q$. This is good enough for completeness because if there's a state that accepts with probability $p \geq a$ then there's an eigenvector with success probability at least $p$. However, I don't think this can be used to show that any "good" witness also accepts w.h.p. after amplification.

In general a "good"  witness $\ket{\psi}$.  will be some linear combination of eigenvectors $\sum_j \alpha_j\ket{\psi_j}$, some of which are "good" and have acceptance probability $\geq a$ and others of which are "bad" and have acceptance probability $\leq b$. Let $S$ be the set of "good" witness eigenvectors. Then, once we amplify, our success probability is roughly (for $r$ large enough I guess)

$$\sum_{j \in S} |\alpha_j|^2(1-2^{-r}).$$

In general $\sum_{j \in S} |\alpha_j|^2$ isn't $1$ so we're in trouble. In the worst case of witness eigenvectors, we can even construct a "good" witness $\ket{\psi}$ that after $r$-rounds of amplification accepts with probability roughly $\frac{a-b}{1-b}(1-2^{-r}) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for $(a,b) = (\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$.